# Sharing via ACTION_SEND: How to make string immutable by user?

Tags: android, android-intent, immutability, sharing, readonly

Is there a way to hand over a string to an ACTION_SEND intent that is read-only to the user and cannot be edited, just sent or not sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant be done.

The reciever (which you dont control) decides how to handle the sent data.

Expanding based on gameowers comment, if you want to do something very specific he is right, you just might want to program your own integration into FB or Twitter.

Comment: Correct! Although if you really need to do something specific, like post on facebook or twitter, or send an e-mail, you can achieve all that individually. Might not be worthy the effort though!